# what makes RPS different from IRQ balance

Tags: linux, linux-networking

i was reading about RPS[Recieve Packet Steering] and how it makes Packets distributed on  different cpus.

I believe IRQbalance also does the same thing by distributing interrupts on different cpu.

IRQbalance will distribute interrupts to different CPU and that CPU will process packet ,since interrupt is distributed to all CPUs,do we still need RPS.